# How to convert 'char' or ''TBuf' to 'TPtrC8'?

Tags: c++, symbian, descriptor

I've a question concerning a conversion from char to TPtrC8 on Symbian. How can I transform a char to TPtrC8 or a TBuf to TPtrC8? Is there a simple and quick way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The `TPtrC8` has constructors that take char* and `TDes8` as arguements. This effectively wraps the `TPtrC8` around the the character array in the char* or the `TBuf8`

`TBuf` is a 16 bit construct and you will have to convert it to a `TBuf8` before you can use it with a `TPtrC8`. If you are using a single character literal, you also might have to put it into a `TBuf8`. `TDes8::Copy` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks and done by the following code:

- TBuf<25> iIMSI; TPtrC iPtrC(iIMSI);
- TPtrC8 iPtrC8((TUint8*)iPtrC.Ptr(), iPtrC.Length()*2);